# Masked image displaying wrong intensity

Tags: image, matlab, mask

I have a 3D image and a mask, both size [256x256x160]. The mask is a binary image of 0 and 255. After applying the mask on the image like so:

```
masked_image = image.*mask;
```

I get a `masked_image` that has totally wrong intensity values. In fact, its values are nowhere to be found on the original image. They are just too big. All I want to achieve is extract the original image's intensities at the location of the mask and calculate the mean value of that ROI. I can see from `imshow` that the mask is aligned properly on the image. However, applying the mask is unsuccessful and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mask` shouldn't be scaled from 0 to 255. It should contain only 0 or 1 to use it the way you want. Any one of these alternatives would work:

```
masked_image = image.*logical(mask);
% Or...
masked_image = image.*(mask > 0);
% Or...
masked_image = image.*(mask./255);
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting the mask to 0 and 1 rather than 0 and 255 solved the problem.
The extracted ROIs now have the correct intensity. 
Thanks for the clarification.